# Getting timeout error (Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node, node-fetch

For my API testing, my code behaving in different ways.I am using jasmine framework with node js.My GET request will give 2 responses

1. Success json, with 200 status code. Response time is 400-500 ms
2. Failure json, with 200 status code (valid failure), Response time is more than 10000 ms

In the 1st case the code for my test cases is below

```
describe('Verification of BS_004_addressCheck',()=>{


    it('Verify success response for BS_004_addressCheck',function(done){
        var path=require('path');
        let endpoint=require(path.resolve('./config/endpoint_BS_004.json'));
       // let pincodes=require(path.resolve('./config/pincodes.json'));

        //let request=require(path.resolve('./config/postPin.json'));

        //console.log(request.id,request.Name);
        const fetch=require('node-fetch');

        let baseUrl=endpoint.url;
        let apikey=endpoint.apikey;
        let country=endpoint.country;
        let postcode=endpoint.postcode;
        let picklistcount=endpoint.picklistcount;
        let uniqueAddressReference=endpoint.uniqueAddressReference;


        let fullUrlWithQueryParameters= baseUrl + "?apikey=" + apikey + "&country=" + country + "&postcode=" + postcode + "&picklistcount=" + picklistcount + "&uniqueAddressReference=" + uniqueAddressReference
        //let pinCode=pincodes.Vlcy;
        console.log(fullUrlWithQueryParameters);
        console.log("test");
        getR(fullUrlWithQueryParameters)
        .then(jsonRes=>{
            console.log(jsonRes);
            expect(jsonRes).not.toBeUndefined();
            expect(jsonRes.Header.ActivityStatusEnum).toBe('SUCCESS');
        })
        .then(done)

    })

})
```

The code in my second case is same as the above. But in my first case, I get the spec as passes and in my second case I get the below failure

```
1) Verification of BS_004_addressCheck Verify success response for BS_004_addressCheck
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at <Jasmine>
        at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 5.012 seconds
Randomized with seed 21049 (jasmine --random=true --seed=21049)
```

My success response will take nearly 400 ms but my failure response will take nearly 10000 ms. So I guessed and added jasmine timeout as below (see above it block)

```
describe('Verification of BS_004_addressCheck',()=>{

    beforeAll(function(done) {
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL= 10000;
    });
   //jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL= 10000; 
    it('Verify success response for BS_004_addressCheck',function(done){
        var path=require('path');
        let endpoint=require(path.resolve('./config/endpoint_BS_004.json'));
       // let pincodes=require(path.resolve('./config/pincodes.json'));

        //let request=require(path.resolve('./config/postPin.json'));

        //console.log(request.id,request.Name);
        const fetch=require('node-fetch');

        let baseUrl=endpoint.url;
        let apikey=endpoint.apikey;
        let country=endpoint.country;
        let postcode=endpoint.postcode;
        let picklistcount=endpoint.picklistcount;
        let uniqueAddressReference=endpoint.uniqueAddressReference;


        let fullUrlWithQueryParameters= baseUrl + "?apikey=" + apikey + "&country=" + country + "&postcode=" + postcode + "&picklistcount=" + picklistcount + "&uniqueAddressReference=" + uniqueAddressReference
        //let pinCode=pincodes.Vlcy;
        console.log(fullUrlWithQueryParameters);
        console.log("test");
        getR(fullUrlWithQueryParameters)
        .then(jsonRes=>{
            console.log(jsonRes);
            expect(jsonRes).not.toBeUndefined();
            expect(jsonRes.Header.ActivityStatusEnum).toBe('SUCCESS');
        })
        .then(done)

    })

})
```

But now I got 2 errors..

```
Failures:
1) Verification of BS_004_addressCheck Verify success response for BS_004_addressCheck
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at <Jasmine>
        at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)

Suite error: Verification of BS_004_addressCheck
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at <Jasmine>
        at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)

1 spec, 2 failures
Finished in 15.015 seconds
Randomized with seed 21999 (jasmine --random=true --seed=21999).
```

I am not sure how to fix this. Please some one help me.The function getR which I call is below

```
let getR = (url) => {
    console.log('test');
    //console.log(url);
    //console.log(id);
    return fetch(url, {method: 'GET', agent: new HttpsProxyAgent('http://10.10.104.4:50683')})

    .then(resRaw =>{
        console.log(resRaw);
        return resRaw.text();
    })
    .then(resJson=>{

        console.log(resJson);
        let res=JSON.parse(resJson);
        //return res;
        console.log(res.Header.ActivityStatusEnum);
        return res;

    })
       //.then(validateResponse);

};
global.get=get;
global.getR=getR;
```

I think the issue is because of long response time. But don't know how to fix this. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your `beforeAll` function callback, you are passing a `done` param but it never gets called, just remove it

```
beforeAll(function() {
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL= 10000;
});
```

[Read the docs about `beforeAll`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/global.html#beforeAll)

Hope it helps